# What should I focus on for a custom PC NOT for gaming?

Tags: computer-building, priority

I'm wanting to build my own powerful PC, but I'm not interested in PC gaming (I prefer my Xbox, thank you). My question is, what components are less or more important for general usage (coding, office, web browsing) as apposed to high graphics gaming? Do they differ at all?

To clarify, I'm not asking for specific hardware to buy, but what *types* of hardware are important.

Comment: Hardware recommendation questions are off-topic here on SuperUser. Please read the Help section to learn more about the sorts of questions that should and should not be asked here: https://superuser.com/help

Comment: If you are not gaming and only doing soft video stuff then you can do without a good graphics card. This question is way to broad and is going to be full opiniated answers. Anyway I'll go for anything Workstation related.

Comment: I'm not looking for specific hardware recommendations like mentioned in the help.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was unaware this was so vague. I'm fairly new to the computer building department. Is there a place this question would be more suited for?

Comment: @MarkDeven I'll try to narrow it down to what I want to do with my pc. Even a toaster can suft the web now days and you can code on extremely cheap hardware.

Comment: You want a forum where open discussion is the purpose. There are also TONS!!!!!!!!! of guides online for building mid-range general-purpose computers. SuperUser is about questions that have a specific correct answer. There is no "correct" answer for a question like this because your needs are going to be different from others, and opinion and experience will play heavily into the solutions suggested and the ones you choose. Forums are about open discussion rather than specific answers, and so are better suited to your needs.

Comment: @dmb A toaster can surf the web, but not the way a power user of a desktop surfs the web. The way I surf, it's not unusual for my browser to be using 4GB of RAM. And when I surf untrusted sites, I use a VM that itself uses about 6GB of RAM. And that's just the surfing.

Comment: I've gotten some good answers and see why this is vague. Can't close the post without deleting it so some more close votes are welcome.

Comment: Questions can be closed, but due to the answers, it will take more for the question to be deleted (it most likely will stick around for awhile)

Comment: Maybe of interest: [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). It is a Beta site, so it may not be promoted to a full Stack Exchange site. (In which case it will die and be archived/read-only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will do what people describe as light-work, which describes web browsing/emails/general usage. I can think of only one intensive operation: code compilation, which usually only takes long with large projects.

You want, in general, a fast CPU (Multi-core is best, but don't go crazy - quad core is more than enough). This defines how fast your computer can run. Then, you want a good amount of RAM - this can get expensive, but from experience I would say that 8 to 16 gigabytes would sort you just fine for now and 5+ years (RAM defines how many programs can run simultaneously, eg chrome tabs, music players, etc).

Storage isn't of the essence, and something like 128GB (or even 64GB potentially) would do you fine. I recommend an SSD - it would seriously speed up your computer in terms of loading.

You don't want to splash on a graphics card at all - you won't be needing it! You can get by using integrated graphics from the CPU, or if you need one, any cheap GPU should do you fine, provided it can support resolutions of upto 1080p or so. A hard drive may be useful for long term storage, but thats beyond the scope of the answer.

The question you've posted is fairly generic in nature and I would recommend you do some research yourself on certain components before asking a question - specifics are better.

Comment: 64bG will barely cover Windows 10 :-(

Comment: Yes, I do agree with you. However, that's Windows. Linux is a viable alternative for OPs use case, but if they wish to use Windows then yes, 128gb and above is highly recommended.

Comment: And cheap enough these days ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Monitor, mouse, and keyboard are very important. Those are the things you are going to be interacting with the most. Second most important is a large, fast SSD for main storage and a large hard drive for secondary storage. Third most important is some way to back the machine up so you don't lose data.